# How to get registry keys and values in listview

Tags: c#, listview, registry

How to get all registry strings and values in listview?
Example:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
  for (int i = 0; i < key.ValueCount; i++)
            {
                string[] arr2 = { key.GetSubKeyNames(), "" };
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(arr2);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

Registry location: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`   and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Comment: Add key.GetSubKeyNames() and key.GetValueNames() listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("Data", 300);

RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");
foreach (string keyName in key.GetValueNames())
{
    listView1.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(
            new string[] { keyName, key.GetValue(keyName).ToString() }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You are enumerating values not keys and so your column header titles are incorrect

Comment: @David Heffernan thanks for your comment. I edited column titles

Answer (score 0):

You code is rather odd. You run a `for` loop with the variable `i`, but then never refer to that variable inside the loop. That's surely a mistake. Assuming that you want to read the values from a key you would write it like this:

```
foreach (string name in key.GetValueNames())
{
    string value = key.GetValue(name).ToString();
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem( new string[] { name, value } );
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The other thing to watch out for is the registry redirector. If your process is 32 bit then your code will read from the 32 bit view of the registry. Which will confuse you when you then look at the registry in regedit. Use the `RegistryView` enumeration to reach both 32 and 64 bit views.

So, on a 64 bit machine, to enumerate both 32 and 64 bit views, for HKLM, you would need to write it like this:

```
private void AddValuesToList(RegistryKey key)
{
    foreach (string name in key.GetValueNames())
    {
        string value = key.GetValue(name).ToString();
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { name, value });
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

which you would call like this:

```
const string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
AddValuesToList(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName));
AddValuesToList(RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
    RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(keyName));
AddValuesToList(RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, 
    RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(keyName));
```

Once you know how to deal with the values, it's easy enough to support the sub keys. Call `key.GetSubKeyNames()` to get hold of them.

Comment: Do you understand the issue with the registry redirector? It doesn't seem that you are bothered by this.